# Add Progress bar to UIAlertController with showing update

Tags: ios, swift3, queue, progress-bar, uialertcontroller

I try to add progress bar on my application. I found the question on [How to add Progress bar to UIAlertController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684482/how-to-add-progress-bar-to-uialertcontroller) but it didn't show how to update the progress bar. I simplify the code as below but it didn't update the progress bar (it shows only once the progress is completed). What did i over look? Thank you for your help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var topViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController!
    while (topViewController.presentedViewController != nil){
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "downloading", message: "pls wait", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let progressBar = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
        progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
        progressBar.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)
        alert.view.addSubview(progressBar)
        topViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        var progress: Float = 0.0
        repeat {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: {
                progress += 0.01
                print (progress)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(flags: .barrier, execute: {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
                })
            })
        } while progress < 1.0
    })
}
```

Comment: How quickly does that progress loop run?
Do you see the printed progress slowly building up, or do all the numbers appear in a flash?

add a little delay in there, load a file or something, and see how it looks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One could get just a little confused by all those dispatch queues in your code :-)

I try to explain the problem:

The **first (outmost)** `DispatchQueue.main.async` is excecuted in the main (UI) thread.
It creates the `UIAlertController`, stuffs the `UIProgressView` into it and displays the dialog. Then it performs **in the main thread** some time-critial job (repeat-while-loop). Never do so, because it **blocks** the main thread. 
Since the main thread is blocked, no updates are reflected in the UI controls, so you don't see progress changes.

Therefore,

- I put the **time critical** work item (repeat loop)  into the *global* queue (not the main queue) as an asynchronous work item

  - Within that work item, I'll dispatch the *progress bar updates* into the main queue (to be executed in the main thread)
  - At the end, when everything is done, I dismiss the `UIAlertController`

You only need the **first** Dispatch when your alert view is shown from a method like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, e.g. from a point in time when the view isn't displayed yet. If you call it from a button callback, or `viewDidAppear` (e.g. view is visible), you could just skip that outer Dispatch.

Here you go - I also put in some sleep time and modified the GCD-Calls a litte to use trailing closures:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var topViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController!
    while (topViewController.presentedViewController != nil){
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!
    }

    // Usage of GCD here is only necessary because it's called from
    // viewDidLoad. If called by viewDidAppear or some action callback, you 
    // don't need it:
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "downloading", message: "pls wait", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let progressBar = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
        progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
        progressBar.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)
        alert.view.addSubview(progressBar)
        topViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        var progress: Float = 0.0
        // Do the time critical stuff asynchronously
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            repeat {
                progress += 0.1
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.25)
                print (progress)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(flags: .barrier) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
                }
            } while progress < 1.0
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas. Your code work as magic. I put my code below as the code with some workload (not the sleep).

Comment: Simplified solution in few lines.

Answer (score 1):

After help from Andreas comment. I work out with this code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var topViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController!
    while (topViewController.presentedViewController != nil){
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "loading", message: "wait please", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)
        let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
        progressView.progress = 0.0
        progressView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        alert.view.addSubview(progressView)
        topViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        var progress = 0.0
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: {
            repeat {
                progress += 0.0001
                print (progress)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(flags: .barrier, execute: {
                    progressView.progress = Float(progress)
                })
            } while progress < 1.0
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
            })
        })

    })
}
```