# Swift: URLRequest in thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous

I want get data from url, but until process complete, i want show loading icon

I use this code but not work for me

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // show loading icon
    // start get data
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // remove loading icon
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add full code of your URLRequest.

Comment: show loading icon? do you want to show a progress bar or a activity indicator.

Comment: @MdRashedPervez i want use indicator until process completed

Comment: @ivarun i want use thread as android thread, URLRequest only is a sample

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898558/add-progress-bar-to-uialertcontroller-with-showing-update/41901773

Comment: @MdRashedPervez thank you

Comment: welcome bro :) @AbarNew

Answer (score 0):

From [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview)

> Threading Considerations
>
> Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the
> main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView
> class from code running in the main thread of your application. The
> only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view
> object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main
> thread.

Which means you should probably show/hide and manipulate therefore your View in the Main thread and not in a background thread as you are doing in "show loading view".